# Не работает Android Virtual Device

Tags: java, android, исключения, эмулятор, avd

При попытке создать в Android Studio в AVD Manager новый девайс, IDE выбрасывает вот такое исключение

> /home/justjew/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_22.ini
>   java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/justjew/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_22.ini
>       at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
>       at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
>       at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
>       at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
>       at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:434)
>       at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:216)
>       at com.android.repository.io.impl.FileSystemFileOp.newFileOutputStream(FileSystemFileOp.java:247)
>       at com.android.repository.io.impl.FileSystemFileOp.newFileOutputStream(FileSystemFileOp.java:235)
>       at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.writeIniFile(AvdManager.java:1673)
>       at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.createAvdIniFile(AvdManager.java:1248)
>       at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.createAvd(AvdManager.java:823)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdManagerConnection.createOrUpdateAvd(AvdManagerConnection.java:582)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdOptionsModel.handleFinished(AvdOptionsModel.java:680)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.handleFinished(ModelWizard.java:350)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.goForward(ModelWizard.java:275)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizardDialog$FinishAction.doAction(ModelWizardDialog.java:309)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$DialogWrapperAction.actionPerformed(DialogWrapper.java:1811)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:857)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:654)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:386)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
>       at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
>       at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
>       at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
>       at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:792)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:465)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1661)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1610)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizardDialog.show(ModelWizardDialog.java:127)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.showAndGet(DialogWrapper.java:1625)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.CreateAvdAction.actionPerformed(CreateAvdAction.java:42)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:857)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:654)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:386)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Я понимаю, что означает этот эксепшн. Но что мне сделать, чтобы этот файл создался?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал использовать эмулятор genymotion, разница велика видна сразу и никаких сбоев не дает. Но сперва загрузите проект, а потом включайте эмулятор.

P.S.: эмулятор бесплатный.

[урок по установке Genymotion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63T-8YRlFmE)

Comment: Genymotion платный

Comment: ты о чем )он бесплатный )я крыса еще тот даж копейку не дам ) у тя ложная инфа

Comment: ответ исправлен

Comment: 3 версии: Indie за $136/год, Business за $412/год и Enterprise - черт его знает за сколько, просят связаться с ними. Community Edition нет

Comment: http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=487687 на тут тоже юксплатная

Comment: бесплатная*  не спорь

Comment: @ДмитрийШелыгин, А Вы попробуйте зарегистрироваться на сайте https://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: прошу прощения, нужно было залогинитсья и появилась кнопка Download

Answer (score 0):

ты пытаешься создать девайс на API_22, а СДК API_22 не установлен
попробуй установи, где я поставил красные галочки и заодно Intel HAXM, тогда стандартный эмулятор будет летать не хуже всяких genymotion

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]